# Is it possible to make parent element (relative) fill the height of its absolute positioned content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, absolute

I'd like my parent div to expand the height of the content, as my content will be dynamic. However, the content must be (I think) positioned absolutely so they can overlap each other vertically.

I've concluded I'll have to use JS to find the offset from the top to the bottom of the last element in the container, then set the height to that.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
var lastElement = document.getElementById('three');
var bounds = lastElement.getBoundingClientRect();
var bottomOffset = bounds.top + $("#three").height();
$("#container").height(bottomOffset);
```

However this is clunky within my application, and the application of the height is not instantaneous, leading to a sluggy site.

Is there a better way?

```js
var lastElement = document.getElementById('three');
var bounds = lastElement.getBoundingClientRect();
var bottomOffset = bounds.top + $("#three").height();
$("#container").height(bottomOffset);
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100% padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.absolute {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#two {
  top: 80px;
  left: 120px
}

#three {
  top: 160px;
  left: 240px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  ;
  background-color: yellow;
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="absolute" id="one"></div>
  <div class="absolute" id="two"></div>
  <div class="absolute" id="three"></div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d815x4h1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish your result without any JS, but instead use CSS `margin` around the boxes to get the same result.

For the horizontal margin you can also use percentages (by request of OP).
For the vertical margins this will give unexpected results, since the percentage will still reference the **[width of the container (under "Property Values")](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-top.asp), not the height**.

```css
html,body {height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box.one {margin-top:0; margin-bottom:160px;}
.box.two {margin-top:80px; margin-bottom:80px;}
.box.three {margin-top:160px; margin-bottom:0;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
  <div class="box three"></div>
</div>
```

**pixel-margin: https://jsfiddle.net/xzq64tsh/**
**percent-margin: https://jsfiddle.net/xzq64tsh/3/**

Comment: I should mention I was need to position the boxes 10% (or some percentage) from the right/left of the screen. Margins wouldn't work for this right?

Comment: @f7n For left/right margin this IS possible, for the top/bottom margin not (because these will still take 10% from the **width of the container**, not the height).

Comment: @f7n For left/right margin, just put this in CSS for `.box`: `margin-right:10%;` or `margin-left:10%;`, or a combination of the two, depending on the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps taking out the `getBoundingClientRect()` function, using jQuery instead might speed it up and simplify it a bit.

```js
var lastElement = $('#three');
var bottomOffset = lastElement.offset().top + lastElement.height();
$("#container").height(bottomOffset);
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100% padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.absolute {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#two {
  top: 80px;
  left: 120px
}

#three {
  top: 160px;
  left: 240px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  ;
  background-color: yellow;
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="absolute" id="one"></div>
  <div class="absolute" id="two"></div>
  <div class="absolute" id="three"></div>
</div>
```